# Redirect to original URL after Login in .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, authentication

My Login code:

```
 public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "Username, Password")] TaiKhoan tk)
        {
            var user = Request["user"];
            if (user != "")
            {
                string username = Request["user"];
                string pass = Request["pass"];
                var t = TaiKhoanBussiness.Login(username, pass, Session);
                if (t != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
                    Session["taikhoan"] = t;
                    var s = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(username, true);
                    Redirect(s);
                }
            }
```

In the action SachController/Comment:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public void Comment() {
   var strDGC = Request["dgc"];
}
```

User is asked for login when Comment. After login, I can't retrieve the last URL before login to redirect back. It's seem the `FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(username, true)` not work?
How can I redirect back after login? The pages are protected by `[Authorise]`so I don't have a link for login to include something like `RedirectURL`

Comment: By default, when forced to login upon accessing an authenticated page, it should append a ?RedirectUrl=/Some/Path.  Do you see that in the URL?  That is the basis for the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your returnUrl to Action

`public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "Username, Password")] TaiKhoan tk, string returnUrl)`

`{`

`.....`

Redirect(returnUrl);

`}`